# Angular 5 directive priority order

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-directive

I have a custom directive I18nx, that replace the text of the element:

```
<button i18nx="Forgot Password?" mat-button></button>
```

how can I run the I18nx before the MatButton, because I change the innerHtml so the MatButton changes are losed.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really change the order of directives, and it wouldn't even help because you can't change the innerHTML of a mat-button runtime without breaking it. You can do this:

```
<button mat-button><span i18nx="Forgot Password?"></span></button>
```